# Hadoop: How to know HDFS file access details?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am planning to do a project for which I need to monitor HDFS file creation, deletion and append operations in real time. [Hadoop metrics](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Metrics.html) tell the number of such operations performed but I need to know the files on which these operations are being done. Logs don't seem to be of much help for this. Is there any framework/technology that would easily allow me to monitor HDFS file operations?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hadoop 2.6+, the native way to do this is by using `inotify` feature that was implemented in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6634

Take a look at this nice presentation from Cloudera: https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/keep-me-in-the-loop-inotify-in-hdfs

Comment: Thank you so much :) I also need to know when a file has been opened just for reading. AFAIK, `inotify` cannot do that. Do you know any workaround to achieve that too?